# What is the init.el in doom emacs?

Tags: init-file, doom

I recently installed `doom emacs` and really like how much it is developed.
The problem I encounter is the following:

I want to add `LSP-support` for emacs. On the [website](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/installation/#doom-emacs), it is illustrated how I can make use of the LSP-Server in doom emacs. I'm not able to find the proper `init.el` file.

Where is it located and how can I make sure it's the correct one?

I ran a global find with

```
find ./ -type f -name "init.el" 2>/dev/null
```

in the `.emacs.d` folder (where I put doom emacs) and got the following output:

```
./modules/config/use-package/init.el
./modules/editor/evil/init.el
./lisp/init.el
./profiles/safe-mode/init.el
./.local/straight/repos/org/testing/jump/test/init.el
./.local/straight/repos/explain-pause-mode/tests/cases/.emacs.d/init.el
./.local/straight/repos/flycheck/test/init.el
```

Which if any is the correct one?

My `.emacs.d directory` looks like this at the moment:

```
bin  docs  early-init.el  eln-cache  LICENSE  lisp  modules  profiles  README.md  shell.nix  templates
```

Comment: Doom gives you easy access to its config files via `SPC f p`.

Comment: @g-gundam Thanks I actually found it this way.

Comment: In most cases it will be in ~/.doom.d

Answer (score 2):

The location of your current init file is stored in the variable `user-init-file`. You can see what its value is by invoking `M-x describe-variable` (I'm not a Doom Emacs user, but I think the keybinding is `SPC h v`) and then provide `user-init-file`.